# What was the decrease in approach speed of the KFIR over the Mirage 5 due to the canards?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, fighter

The Mirage III approached at 170 knots according to the Dassault. The Mirage NG and the KFIR C2 as well as the Swiss Mirage 5s added canards to the design, what was the decrease in approach speed due to these changes? I see improvements in low speed handling stated in some references, but does anyone have any references to the approach speeds of the modified aircraft?

Comment: The Dassault Aviation website gives the following information: https://www.dassault-aviation.com/en/defense/customer-support/operational-aircraft/mirage-5/  : Landing Speed: 180 mph which works out to 156 knots. The reference given by atacusa seems high.  The Dassault site gives the approach speed for the Mirage 2000 as "140 Kts".

Answer (score 1):

The KFIR has similar airspeed specs as the Mirage 5. However, I'm not clear on what you mean by "Approach Speed".

Approach and Landing Phase:

- Vectoring Speed: 220-250 kts
- Max Gear Speed: 270kts
- Approach Speed: 190-200 kts
- Touchdown Speed: 170-180kts

[Source](http://www.atacusa.com/images/KFIR_ATC_Briefing.pdf)